# How can I change createuserwizard's default database to my database in asp.net 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using the create user wizard of C# asp.net 4. I want to change its default database (i.e. `ASPNETDB.mdf`) to my own created database (i.e. `test.mdf`).

How can I do this? and one more thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 step required .

First need to run `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool which is located in `[YouWinDrive]:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and in this wizard while you target your arbitrary database create necessary objects .

Step2 : you need to config your asp.net membership provider . as you may know web.config file inherites from Machine.config file which is locatd in `[YouWinDrive]:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`

if you look at that file you will find out Default AspNetSqlMembershipProvider is targeted in sqlserver express and aspnetDB :

```
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

So you need to override this membership in your web.config file like this :

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
                     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                     connectionStringName="YourConnectionToArbitraryDatabase"
                     enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
                     enablePasswordReset="true"
                     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                     applicationName="YourAppName"
                     requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                     passwordFormat="Encrypted"
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                     minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
                     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                     passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                     passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

and you can change it as you would like .

Comment: that means I have to connectionStringName="server=.,database=test,integrated security=true" and applicationName="MyProject's name" ?

Comment: Its Ok. I got it...Now only thing remaining is how to use it in c# code behing if I want to pass a query.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard creates a connection string that is stored in your web.config file that is located in the root folder of your web application. Just open this file and change the connection string appropriately.

Here is an example of a connection string how it looks in one of my projects:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

So, you just basically have to change the filename. You can also provide the full path to your database if you want.